# Powershell or cmd - How to search for a file on client and replace with a different file on network share?

Tags: powershell, cmd, scripting, sccm

We are looking to replace the defaultlayouts.xml for all profiles when upgrading to Windows 10 Pro v. 1607.  This will be accomplished with SCCM site-wide.  We have the new layoutmodification.xml configured and ready for deployment however, we are struggling to push this to all profiles due to the variation of users on a client machine.  No issues deploying to the 'default' profile.

The defaultlayouts.xml lives here: C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell

The variable will be johndoe.

Multiple users' profiles may exist on the client, so we need to search the 'c:\users' folder for the defaultlayouts.xml in each user's profile.

If the file exists in any of the profiles we want to delete it then copy the layoutmodification.xml from a network share.

I have experience in scripting, powershell and SCCM. Any ideas, thoughts, comments, and recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you can just use a wildcard in the path for the username portion and it will search for every user available. So, you could do something like this:

```
gci C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\shell\defaultlayouts.xml | % {

    move $_.fullname "$($_.fullname)_bak"
    copy sourcelocation $_.fullname
    #alternatively to copy, you could do something like call a download if it's stored on a intranet site for example

}
```

Comment: assuming it's just available via a url

`Invoke-WebRequest -Uri www.filestoredhere.com -OutFile $_.fullname`

there are alternative ways to download files that are faster but for a small .xml this should be fine

Answer (score 1):

Find all defaultlayouts.xml files in C:\Users. Then delete each item and copy layoutmodification.xml file from networkshare.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\shell\defaultlayouts.xml  | ForEach-Object {
    Remove-Item $_.FullName
    Copy-Item \\server\layoutmodification.xml  $(Split-Path $_.FullName)
}
```

EDIT: Changed to wildcard path -> C:\Users*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\shell\defaultlayouts.xml from just C:\Users\ -recurse

Thank you Noah Sparks

Comment: Recursing C:\users is going to take an incredibly long time as opposed to just targeting the file you want using a wildcard in the changing portion of the path.